# clearinterval not stopping setInterval function getting called - nodejs with socket io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

on the client side i just set up two buttons, one to call socket.on('start-white-clock') and another to call socket.on('start-black-clock')

it's for a chess game

my aim is to stop the white timer when the black timer starts vice versa

with the code below when i call socket.on('start-black-clock')  which calls the function blackClock()  the function starts and begins to count down - logging blackClockTime: 18000, 17990, 17980 ..... etc etc

though when i then call socket.on('start-white-clock') which calls
clearInterval(blackClock);

its doesn't stop blackClock() logging blackClockTime: 18000, 17990, 17980 ..... etc etc it just keeps going as if nothing has happened?

//server.js

```
const express = require('express'); //Line 1
const app = express(); //Line 2

const http = require('http').Server(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(5000)


var time = 180000





//Whenever someone connects this gets executed
io.on('connection', socket => {

    console.log('A user connected - this is socket.id: ' + socket.id);

    //Whenever someone disconnects this piece of code executed
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
       console.log('Socket disconnected: ' + socket.id)
    });

    socket.on("join-game", (usersEmail, gameId, pageCalledFrom) => {
        socket.join(gameId)
theGameId = gameId
    })







var blackClockOn = false
  var blackClockTime = 18000
 
function blackClock() {
     blackClockTime = blackClockTime - 10
     console.log("blackClockTime: " + blackClockTime)
}


var theGameId;
var whiteClockTime = 18000
var whiteClockOn = false
function whiteClock() {
    whiteClockTime = whiteClockTime - 10
    console.log("white clock time: " + whiteClockTime)
  
}




//start white 
socket.on('start-white-clock',(usersEmail,currentGameId) => {
    console.log("start white clock called")
    whiteClock() 
     setInterval(whiteClock, 1000);
    clearInterval(blackClock); 

})


    //start black 
    socket.on('start-black-clock',(usersEmail,currentGameId) => {
        console.log("start black clock called")
        blackClock()
        setInterval(blackClock, 1000);
       clearInterval(whiteClock); 
    })
```

Comment: The argument you pass to `clearInterval` **MUST** be the value (id) returned by `setInterval`. It cannot be anything else. In your case you do not save the value returned by `setInterval` to a variable. You need to do that

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval#examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `clearInterval()` receives an integer as an argument. this integer is the id of the interval, which is returned by the function `setInterval()`.
so you would need to define 2 variables outside of the `socket.on()` callbacks:
`let blackInterval, whiteInterval;` 
then

```
socket.on('start-white-clock',(usersEmail,currentGameId) => {
console.log("start white clock called")
whiteClock() 
whiteInterval = setInterval(whiteClock, 1000);
if(blackInterval) clearInterval(blackInterval);
})
```

and

```
  socket.on('start-black-clock',(usersEmail,currentGameId) => {
    console.log("start black clock called")
    blackClock()
    blackInterval = setInterval(blackClock, 1000);
// conditional not needed here as white always starts so its interval should be defined
   clearInterval(whiteInterval); 
})
```

Comment: muchas gracias Manuel works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
const intervalID = setInterval(.....);
clearInterval(intervalID);
```